# How to get a new column with sum of even/odd/kth rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas series:

```
ts = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

What I would like to get is a dataframe which contains another column with the sum of rows 0, 2, 4, 6 and for 1, 3, 5 and 7 (that means, one row is left out when creating the sum).

In this case, this means a new dataframe should look like this one:

```
index ts sum
0 1 16
1 2 20
2 3 16
3 4 20
4 5 16
5 6 20
6 7 16
7 8 20
```

How could I do this?

Comment: You really want to create a new column to store this, repeatedly? You can always trivially access this with `ts.groupby(ts.index % 2).sum()`. That's what I usually do with aggregates, keep them in a separate, smaller summary dataframe; it reduces memory waste.

Comment: Vaguely related: [Pandas - append column with sum of row values (if sum is even), or NaN (if odd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53512640/pandas-append-column-with-sum-of-even-row-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use modulo by `k` for each kth rows:

```
k = 2
df = ts.to_frame('ts')
df['sum'] = df.groupby(ts.index % k).transform('sum')
#if not default RangeIndex
#df['sum'] = df.groupby(np.arange(len(ts)) % k).transform('sum')
print (df)
   ts  sum
0   1   16
1   2   20
2   3   16
3   4   20
4   5   16
5   6   20
6   7   16
7   8   20
```